# How can I connect to LiveMeetings after uninstalling the Lync 2010 Client?

Tags: live-meeting

After installing the Lync 2010 Client and setting a manual configuration, I subsequently uninstalled Lync and now I can't connect to OCS 2007 Live Meetings. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple.

Using Regedit, browse to the following key:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Shared\UcClient

Set ConfigurationMode to 0
Clear the ServerSipUri value data.
Clear the ServerUsername value data.